# npm install request has been deprecated

Tags: node.js

I am new to nodejs and I am trying a simple task or program that builds API to get the current weather of a city from this website: https://openweathermap.org/

i tested the get api in POSTMAN and able to give me the correct result, however when I tried it already in nodejs, the result is "undefined"

this is the code

```
const request = require("request");

const url = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=922a0c3b43f4d078f19599ff2fda6";

request(url, (error, response, body) => {
console.log(body)

})
```

I understand that I should install first the request module using this line

```
npm install request
```

But the output says the it is already deprecated. Could it be the reason why is not successful? What should be the workaround?

[image]

Comment: warnings can be ignored.

Comment: `axios` is a popular modern replacement for `request`. You will probably run into more warnings as you keep using request.

Comment: you mean doing "npm install axios" instead?

Comment: Look got request-promise or superagent or axios

Comment: The problem was caused by a typo (`http(s)://` missing from the start of the URL). Voting to close ("Caused by a typo" is a standard  close reason). You can just delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

Check the status code first before you do the `console.log`. You can try something like this,

```
const request = require("request");

const url = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=922a0c3b43f4d078f19599ff2fda6";

request(url, (error, response, body) => {
   if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body) 
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to David R suggestion and was able to locate that the problem is my URI is INVALID

should append: http:// in the URI and it worked as expected.

Here is the final code

```
const request = require("request");

const url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=922a0c3b43f4d078f19599ff2fda6";

request(url, (error, response, body) => {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body) 
    }
    else
    {
        console.log(error)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the native node `fetch` (node >= 18).

```js
async function logMovies() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch("http://example.com/movies.json");
    const movies = await response.json();
    console.log(movies);
  } catch(error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

[Using fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

[The Fetch API is finally stable in Node.js](https://blog.logrocket.com/fetch-api-node-js/)

Answer (score -1):

Also if you are looking for an alternative package that is not deprecated, the POSTMAN organization has forked the request module and they're continuing to support it, releasing new versions.

[www.npmjs.com/package/postman-request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postman-request)

```js
npm i postman-request
```

Answer (score -1):

The solution in the same output message :

```
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
```

So, you can upgrade to version 7 or higher.
Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.

Comment: That isn't the solution. The solution is to use a real URL.